# Static IP working slow in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dns, static-ip

In ubuntu 15.04 I have, in order to have a static IP in my LAN, updated /etc/network/interfaces to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.140
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255
dns-nameservers *.*.*.* *.*.*.* *.*.*.*
```

where the last three ip's are DNS of my internet provider and are the same as nmcli returns when using dhcp.

Internet works but is very slow (at least name resolving), to ping www.google.com it takes about 5 seconds. When i use DHCP it is instant.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: change your nameserver, eg: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

Comment: I prefer a local nameserver from my internet provider.

Comment: Than ask your internet provider :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I will just wait for someone competent to answer it here.